# SpGridView and Get Selected Row Data

Tags: development, application-pages, user-controls

I am using SPGridView. I want to fill textboxes with the SPGridview Selected Row Data on a button click event.

Does anyone know how to do that?

My code:

```
txtCode= SPGridView.SelectedRow.Cell[1].Text;
```

But when debugging it shows Cell[1] is empty even though it is showing data in the Grid.

Any ideas?

Thanks 
SAAD

Answer (score 1):

is SPGridView.SelectedRow.Cell[1].Text empty? Or is SPGridView.SelectedRow.Cell[1] null?

If it's not null, have a look at SPGridView.SelectedRow.Cell[1].Controls, maybe there is a LiteralControl contained in the cell or something that contains the text you are looking for.

Comment: SPGridView contain data ,its not null or empty.

Comment: Did you read the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that txtCode is a TextBox should that not read

```
txtCode.Text = SPGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
```

Comment: having same problem with txtCode.text